# paas the file as an argument to the ExcelRead java function

Tags: servlets

I am new in java family. Please help as soon as possible.
I have created a jsp page in which I have given

```
<INPUT NAME="F1" TYPE="file" id="i1" > 
<p align="left"><INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="submit">
```

and browse an excel file on it and click the submit button.
Now I create a java class ExcelRead extends HttpServlet in which I use post method.

I want to extract the file (path) which I browse in jsp page as 
ServletInputStream contentType = request.getInputStream();

and paas that in ExcelRead function..as..
excel.readExcelSheet(contentType);

And then the coding part which is able to read excel sheet.
But when I run the jsp page in server after clicking the submit button it's throwing an exception:-

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_03\bin\keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)...
java.lang.StackOverflowError...
```

Can any one suggest me what to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.DiskFileUpload`

```
              DiskFileUpload fu = new DiskFileUpload();
              fu.setSizeThreshold(1024);
              fu.setRepositoryPath(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
              List fileList = fu.parseRequest(request);
              InputStream uploadedFileStream = null;
              for (Iterator i = fileList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
              {
                FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
                if (fi.getSize() < 1)
                  {
                    throw new Exception("No file was uplaoded");
                  }

                  uploadedFileStream = fi.getInputStream();
                  excel.readExcelSheet(uploadedFileStream );
              }
}
```

In ExcelRead you have to change the method parameter to `readExcelSheet(InputStream is)`
Hope it helps you.

Comment: public class ExcelRead extends HttpServlet {

  ExcelRead excel = new ExcelRead();
  
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
  DiskFileUpload fu = new DiskFileUpload();
  fu.setSizeThreshold(1024);  
  fu.setRepositoryPath(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
  List fileList = null;
  try {
   fileList = (List) fu.parseRequest(request);
  } catch (FileUploadException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } InputStream uploadedFileStream = null;

Comment: for (Iterator i = ((java.util.List) fileList).iterator(); i.hasNext(); )  
  {                 FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();   
  if (fi.getSize() < 1)             
  {                     
   System.out.print("No file was uplaoded");                
   }      
  uploadedFileStream = fi.getInputStream();     
  excel.readExcelSheet(uploadedFileStream );

Comment: public void readExcelSheet(InputStream uploadedFileStream){ 
     
        
     try {
          Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(uploadedFileStream);
          System.out.println("Testing");
          System.out.println("No of sheet in workbook:="+wb.getNumberOfSheets());
             for(int sheetNo=0; sheetNo<wb.getNumberOfSheets();sheetNo++)
             {                 
               Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetNo);
               int columns = sheet.getColumns();int rows = sheet.getRows();
               String data;

Comment: System.out.println("Sheet Name\t"+wb.getSheet(sheetNo).getName()); 
                       for(int row = 0;row < rows;row++) {
                           for(int col = 0;col < columns;col++) {
                            data = sheet.getCell(col, row).getContents();
                           System.out.print("-> "+data+ " ");
                          
                       }                           
                       System.out.println("\n"); 
                   }
                   }
               } catch(Exception ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
               }}

Comment: still it's throwing LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_03\bin\keystore (The system cannot find the path specified) as exception.. :( also java.lang.StackOverflowError.. nw what next change i hv 2 make?

Comment: thats something different.. plz refer this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/printer/ssl-howto.html

Comment: @ Ramesh: thnks for looking it again..is this means the java program logic is correct? means here i neend to paas the excel file(coming from jsp page using input type=file tab)) to that excelRead method is correctly written,error is something diffent than coding?

Comment: yes @user1586634, your java code is perfect. go through the link i gave and do it accordingly. Are you using SSL?

Comment: @ Ramesh : no i dont have any idea about SSL :( m new with java family.. i had just use eclipse tool in which tomcat is the server.. i make one project in which 1 jsp n one java class  prepared,.. just tell me one more thing that if this code will run then output(excel file data) will be shown in console,right? becoz previously i had make one java project which have one java code as include in excelRead method here.. then after running the project output was in console..

Comment: @ Ramesh: Thnks alots.. one more thing plz.. if i install the tomcat server again in my system then whether this error will remove?

Comment: Yes you are right, please use another tomcat server, and moreover dont go for installation, use non installer.

Comment: if you are satisfied with my answer, plz accept it as an answer?

Comment: @ Ramesh:in your coding for (Iterator i = fileList.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) it's showing method iterator is undefined for type List.. when go for typecast and write as for (Iterator i = ((java.util.List) fileList).iterator(); i.hasNext(); )  it'as show one warning that Multiple markers at this line
 - Iterator is a raw type. References to generic type Iterator<E> should be 
  parameterized
 - Line breakpoint:ExcelRead [line: 37] - doPost(HttpServletRequest, 
  HttpServletResponse)
 - List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized.. what to do now?

Comment: @ ramesh: can u plz see once again my coding properly,and let me know whether it's perfect or hv some mistake? because it's not running correctly.. same exception it's throwing.. one of my senior told me not to use diskupload,try to use another way,a/c to him error is in my coding logic..